# How can I assign HTML attribute values using handlebars.js?

Tags: handlebars.js

Let's say I have this following HTML code -

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" />
```

Which I want to convert to

```
<input type="{{type}}" placeholder="{{text}}" />
```

How can I do this using Handlebars.js?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to use a templating engine to generate a template? Although probably possible, is that really what you want?

Comment: Yeah, kinda makes sense in my problem context.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem context in some more detail? I don't see why you would want (or need) to use a templating engine to transform text that isn't currently written in that engine's template language. An HTML parser would be a much better fit, by the looks of it.